# Confidence interval(s) for randomization design

Tags: confidence-interval, permutation-test

I am developing a method to do something with permutation testing. I have two permutation / randomization schemes and do not know which one is better than the other. Can I find the confidence interval for each permutation scheme? If so, is the one with the narrower confidence region better?